# How to prevent tsc to generate unused declaration files given a single entry file

Tags: typescript, tsc, .d.ts

Given this tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDeclarationOnly": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDir": ".",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "include": ["src/index.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Given source files

src/index.ts

```
import { TEST } from './test'
```

src/test.ts

```
export const TEST = 'test';
```

After I run `tsc` it generated both `/dist/index.d.ts` & `dist/index.d.ts`

Since index.ts didn't re-export anything from test.ts.

I expect the test.d.ts to not be generated since it won't be used
given an entry point is `src/index.ts`;

If this can't be done natively by `tsc`, Are there any tools I could remove unused .d.ts files in the second step?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/38592), but you didn't show the contents of `index.d.ts`, so not sure.